# how to change the jquery ui theme dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have three text box with jquery ui date picker 
Now what i need is i need to add the theme dynamically for each date picker i need separate theme is it possible to do ?

Please check my [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/710/) here

**Html**

```
<p>Date:  <input id="datepicker" type="text"> </p>  <br/>
<p>Date1: <input id="datepicker1" type="text"> </p> <br/>
<p>Date2:  <input id="datepicker2" type="text"></p> <br/>
```

**Jquery Datepicker**

```
$('#datepicker').theme('01'); // default theme
$('#datepicker1').theme('02'); // blue theme
$('#datepicker2').theme('03'); // browntheme
```

Comment: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using-multiple-jquery-ui-themes-on-a-single-page.html  One other way would be to use `scoped` boolean attribute but still not browser supported AFAIK  EDIT: regarding scoped support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633425/1414562