# Scoped CSS not being applied within the component

Tags: css, vue.js

I have the following form component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input placeholder="Recipe Name">
            <textarea placeholder="Recipe Description..." rows="10"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'AddRecipeForm'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

The `<style>` uses the `scoped` attribute.

When applied, the CSS **does not** get loaded in. When `scoped` is removed, it ***does*** get applied.

However I want to keep it local to the component.

Why is the CSS not getting applied when the `scoped` attribute is present?

Comment: I just needed to refresh the page. Apparently webpack doesn't auto-reload the page when the `scoped` attribute is applied

Comment: hot reload should work with scoped styles. Make sure you have your hot reload setup properly: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633425/943435

Comment: @alanbuchanan Please select an answer for this question if one was provided.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For some reason, scoped styles don't get applied during hot reload when they are first added to the component. Full page reload fixes the issue, from there the styles, since they have been detected, get updated with consecutive hot reloads.

Answer (score 113):

It appears this was solved by doing a full-reload of the page. Hot reload should take care of scoped css.

However for future viewers, This is commonly asked when scoped CSS isnt being applied to a child component. This can be solved by using [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html). (e.g:  Using a `.selector >>> .desired-selector {}`)

EDIT: Since this is still getting activity, I'll bring my comment into the answer. `::v-deep` also works depending on what preprocessor you're using.

---

**Vue 3 Edit**

Now that Vue 3 is stable and been in full release for a while, see the Vue 3 docs for deep selectors: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css

Namely, this syntax is now: `:deep(.some-class)`. There are also some new features which can be read in the linked docs above.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me as well. I couldn't get any css I was writing to hit the DOM until using the >>> Deep selector, now it all works!

Comment: Use `/deep/` (including slashes) when using SCSS instead of plain CSS, because the SCSS parser doesn't handle `>>>`.

Comment: @RameshPareek try ::v-deep as well. It depends on your CSS loader

Comment: it worked. Please delete your comment. so as not to confuse future visitors.

Comment: @BrandonDeo This was the correct solution for me. 
Using SCSS ``::v-deep`` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Precisely same symptoms as the OP but none of the recommendations here so far have worked and I need to move on so our solution is to rely on CSS selectors normally:

- add a uniquely-named class to the top-level element below <template>
- prefix all scoped (non-global) selectors with that uniquely-named class

which had the unexpected but welcome upside when live-debugging our CSS is that the origin of the CSS rule is now obvious in devtools.

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <v-card class="MyComponent" ... >
        <div class="fancyBox" ... >
         /* ... */
    </v-card>
</template>

<style>
    .MyComponent .fancyBox { /* scoped to any MyComponent instance */ }
    .globalBox { /* we wouldn't put a global style here, obv */ }
</style>
```

Yes, it's a pain to prefix component-scoped styles this way, but, at least it's a familiar thing to do and you get the added benefit in devtools of tracing the source of a style back to the component that declared it.

Caveat is that, of course, parent-scoped CSS will also bleed down to child-scopes. This, at least, is familiar CSS behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the Vue App by running 'yarn serve' has fixed the problem for me.