# Change properties in subclasses

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am developing a project using Vue and Vuetify, I want to turn off opacity inside the "v-btn__overlay" class, which comes under v-btn,

```
<script setup>
.
.
.
</script>

<template lang="pug">
Banner(splashArtPath = 'valorant' title= 'VALORANT' subtitle= 'Time to RISE UP!')
  GamesMenu(gameName='VALORANT' gameImagePath='valorant')
v-divider.border-opacity-100(thickness="1rem")
.boostType
  .buttons
    v-btn.boost-type-button(v-for="boostType in boostTypes" size="x-large" :to='`${boostType.route}`' ) {{ boostType.name }}
  .dynamic-view
    router-view()
</template>

<style scoped>
.v-divider {
  border-color: #f83e4b !important;
}
.boostType {
  background-color: #341017;
  font-family: Inter;
}
.buttons {
  padding: 2rem 2.75rem;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1.375rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.v-btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #444444;
}

/* doesn't work */
.v-btn--active > .v-btn__overlay, .v-btn[aria-haspopup=menu][aria-expanded=true] > .v-btn__overlay {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.v-btn--active {
  background-color: #D42D2D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.v-btn:hover {
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}
.dynamic-view {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

This is what apppear while inspect
[image]

this is what I want

[image]

```
/* doesn't work */
.v-btn--active > .v-btn__overlay, .v-btn[aria-haspopup=menu][aria-expanded=true] > .v-btn__overlay {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

I have tried this but doesnt work, I just want to close opacity value, if my title doesnt fit this question please feel free to change.

```
   <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1111.0" data-gr-ext-installed="" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <div id="app" data-v-app=""><div class="v-responsive v-img image" data-v-3587acbb="" data-v-10de7fed=""><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 37.5694%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--cover" src="/src/assets/banners/valorant.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="content" data-v-3587acbb=""><div class="appbar" data-v-fec72dec="" data-v-3587acbb=""><button type="button" class="v-btn v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-default v-btn--variant-tonal logo" data-v-fec72dec=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><div class="navigation-and-buttons" data-v-fec72dec=""><div class="navigations" data-v-fec72dec=""><div class="navigation-text" variant="text" data-v-fec72dec="">BOOSTING</div><div class="navigation-text" variant="text" data-v-fec72dec="">COACHING</div><div class="navigation-text" variant="text" data-v-fec72dec="">MARKETPLACE</div></div><div class="buttons" data-v-fec72dec=""><div class="v-responsive v-img profile" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="v-menu-1" data-v-c4fe75ea=""><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/profiles/profile-ahri.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="settings" data-v-2a917737="" data-v-fec72dec=""><i class="mdi-cog mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" data-v-2a917737="" style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); caret-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);"></i></div></div></div></div><div class="TRUST-PILOT-5-STAR-REVIEW" data-v-3587acbb="">** TRUST PILOT 5 STAR REVIEW **</div><div class="title" data-v-3587acbb="">VALORANT</div><div class="subtitle" data-v-3587acbb="">Time to RISE UP!</div><div class="dynamic" data-v-3587acbb=""><div class="select-games" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="v-menu-2" data-v-37e55ae4=""><div class="game-image" data-v-37e55ae4=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-37e55ae4=""><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 97.2973%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/icons/valorant.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div><div class="a" data-v-37e55ae4="">●</div><div class="game-name" data-v-37e55ae4="">VALORANT</div><i class="mdi-menu-down mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" data-v-37e55ae4=""></i></div><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--></div></div></div></div><hr class="v-divider v-theme--light border-opacity-100" aria-orientation="horizontal" role="separator" data-v-10de7fed="" style="border-top-width: 1rem;"><div class="boostType" data-v-10de7fed=""><div class="buttons" data-v-10de7fed=""><a class="v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/division" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">DIVISION BOOST</span><!----><!----></a><a class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/win" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">WIN BOOST</span><!----><!----></a><a class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/placements" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">PLACEMENTS</span><!----><!----></a><a class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/unrated-match" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">UNRATED MATCH</span><!----><!----></a><a class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/premier" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">PREMIER</span><!----><!----></a><a class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated boost-type-button" href="/boosting/valorant/contracts" data-v-10de7fed=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">CONTRACTS</span><!----><!----></a></div><div class="dynamic-view" data-v-10de7fed=""><div class="division-boost" data-v-b88128ff="" data-v-10de7fed=""><div class="current-rank" data-v-0b08b0f5="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="width: 28rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 228.613%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/valorant-player-card.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="content" data-v-0b08b0f5=""><div class="title" data-v-0b08b0f5="">CURRENT RANK</div><div class="v-responsive v-img act-rank" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="width: 10rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/act-rank-level1.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="v-responsive v-img rank-icon" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="width: 3.5rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/ranks/valorant/silver-1.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div></div><div class="title" data-v-0b08b0f5="">silver I</div><div class="colors" data-v-0b08b0f5=""><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(122, 122, 122); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(66, 17, 6); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192); height: 2rem; width: 2rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(238, 175, 12); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(58, 205, 127); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(196, 135, 245); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-0b08b0f5="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 49, 86); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button></div><div class="selections" data-v-0b08b0f5=""><div class="v-input v-input--horizontal v-input--density-default v-input--dirty v-input--readonly v-text-field v-select v-select--single v-select--selected" data-v-0b08b0f5=""><!----><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-field v-field--active v-field--appended v-field--dirty v-field--no-label v-field--variant-solo v-theme--light" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="v-menu-18"><div class="v-field__overlay"></div><div class="v-field__loader"><div class="v-progress-linear v-theme--light" role="progressbar" aria-hidden="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; --v-progress-linear-height: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"><!----><div class="v-progress-linear__background" style="width: 100%;"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate"><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate long"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate short"></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><div class="v-field__field" data-no-activator=""><!----><label class="v-label v-field-label" for="input-16"><!----><!----></label><!----><div class="v-field__input" data-no-activator=""><!----><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="v-select__selection"><span class="v-select__selection-text">20-0 RR<!----></span></div><input readonly="" size="1" type="text" id="input-16" aria-describedby="input-16-messages" outline="" height="20"></div><!----></div><!----><div class="v-field__append-inner"><!----><i class="mdi-menu-down mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="v-field__outline"><!----><!----></div></div></div><!----><div class="v-input__details"><div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="input-16-messages"></div><!----></div></div><div class="buttons" data-v-0b08b0f5=""><div class="button" data-v-0b08b0f5="">I</div><div class="button" data-v-0b08b0f5="">II</div><div class="button" data-v-0b08b0f5="">III</div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="desired-rank" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-b88128ff="" style="width: 28rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 228.613%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/valorant-player-card.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="content" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="title" data-v-b88128ff="">DESIRED RANK</div><div class="v-responsive v-img act-rank" data-v-b88128ff="" style="width: 10rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/act-rank-level3.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="v-responsive v-img rank-icon" data-v-b88128ff="" style="width: 3.5rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/ranks/valorant/gold-2.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div></div><div class="title" data-v-b88128ff="">gold II</div><div class="colors" data-v-b88128ff=""><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(122, 122, 122); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(66, 17, 6); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(238, 175, 12); height: 2rem; width: 2rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(58, 205, 127); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(196, 135, 245); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--variant-elevated color" data-v-b88128ff="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 49, 86); height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><!----></span><!----><!----></button></div><div class="selections" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-input v-input--horizontal v-input--density-default v-input--dirty v-input--readonly v-text-field v-select v-select--single v-select--selected" data-v-b88128ff=""><!----><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-field v-field--active v-field--appended v-field--dirty v-field--no-label v-field--variant-solo v-theme--light" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="v-menu-28"><div class="v-field__overlay"></div><div class="v-field__loader"><div class="v-progress-linear v-theme--light" role="progressbar" aria-hidden="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; --v-progress-linear-height: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"><!----><div class="v-progress-linear__background" style="width: 100%;"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate"><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate long"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate short"></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><div class="v-field__field" data-no-activator=""><!----><label class="v-label v-field-label" for="input-26"><!----><!----></label><!----><div class="v-field__input" data-no-activator=""><!----><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="v-select__selection"><span class="v-select__selection-text">Turkey<!----></span></div><input readonly="" size="1" type="text" id="input-26" aria-describedby="input-26-messages" outline="" height="20"></div><!----></div><!----><div class="v-field__append-inner"><!----><i class="mdi-menu-down mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="v-field__outline"><!----><!----></div></div></div><!----><div class="v-input__details"><div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="input-26-messages"></div><!----></div></div><div class="milestones" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="milestone" data-v-b88128ff="">I</div><div class="milestone" data-v-b88128ff="">II</div><div class="milestone" data-v-b88128ff="">III</div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="checkout" data-v-ad830943="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-ad830943="" style="width: 33.81rem;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 240.255%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/checkout.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-responsive__content"><div class="checkout-content" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="text-checkout" data-v-ad830943="">CHECKOUT</div><div class="solo-duo" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="solo" data-v-ad830943="">SOLO</div><div class="v-input v-input--horizontal v-input--density-default v-switch v-switch--inset" data-v-ad830943=""><!----><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-selection-control v-selection-control--density-default"><div class="v-selection-control__wrapper"><div class="v-switch__track"></div><div class="v-selection-control__input"><!----><input id="switch-29" aria-disabled="false" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="switch-29-messages" value="true"><div class="v-switch__thumb"><!----></div></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><div class="v-input__details"><div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="switch-29-messages"></div><!----></div></div><div class="duo" data-v-ad830943="">DUO</div></div><div class="lane-selection" data-v-ad830943=""></div><div class="order-options" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="checkout-selection" data-v-fe7abde9="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="row" data-v-fe7abde9=""><i class="mdi-help-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="v-tooltip-32" data-v-fe7abde9=""></i><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="title" data-v-fe7abde9="">BOOSTER</div><div class="empty" data-v-fe7abde9=""></div></div><div class="slot" data-v-fe7abde9=""><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-default v-btn--variant-elevated" data-v-b88128ff=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><i class="mdi-plus-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><!----><!----></button></div></div><div class="checkout-selection" data-v-fe7abde9="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="row" data-v-fe7abde9=""><i class="mdi-help-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="v-tooltip-34" data-v-fe7abde9=""></i><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="title" data-v-fe7abde9="">AGENTS</div><div class="empty" data-v-fe7abde9=""></div></div><div class="slot" data-v-fe7abde9=""><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-btn--icon v-theme--light v-btn--density-default v-btn--size-default v-btn--variant-elevated" data-v-b88128ff=""><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><i class="mdi-plus-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><!----><!----></button></div></div><div class="checkout-selection" data-v-fe7abde9="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="row" data-v-fe7abde9=""><i class="mdi-help-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="v-tooltip-36" data-v-fe7abde9=""></i><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="title" data-v-fe7abde9="">BONUS WIN</div><div class="empty" data-v-fe7abde9=""></div></div><div class="slot" data-v-fe7abde9=""><div class="display-flex" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-b88128ff="" style="width: 50px;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/icons/high-mmr.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div><div class="v-input v-input--horizontal v-input--density-default v-switch" data-v-b88128ff=""><!----><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-selection-control v-selection-control--density-default"><div class="v-selection-control__wrapper"><div class="v-switch__track"></div><div class="v-selection-control__input"><!----><input id="switch-37" aria-disabled="false" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="switch-37-messages" value="true"><div class="v-switch__thumb"><!----></div></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><div class="v-input__details"><div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="switch-37-messages"></div><!----></div></div></div></div></div><div class="checkout-selection" data-v-fe7abde9="" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="row" data-v-fe7abde9=""><i class="mdi-help-circle mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="v-tooltip-40" data-v-fe7abde9=""></i><!--teleport start--><!--teleport end--><div class="title" data-v-fe7abde9="">PREMİUM</div><div class="empty" data-v-fe7abde9=""></div></div><div class="slot" data-v-fe7abde9=""><div class="display-flex" data-v-b88128ff=""><div class="v-responsive v-img" data-v-b88128ff="" style="width: 50px;"><div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 87.7193%;"></div><img class="v-img__img v-img__img--contain" src="/src/assets/icons/premium.png" alt="" style=""><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div><div class="v-input v-input--horizontal v-input--density-default v-switch" data-v-b88128ff=""><!----><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-selection-control v-selection-control--density-default"><div class="v-selection-control__wrapper"><div class="v-switch__track"></div><div class="v-selection-control__input"><!----><input id="switch-41" aria-disabled="false" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="switch-41-messages" value="true"><div class="v-switch__thumb"><!----></div></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><div class="v-input__details"><div class="v-messages" role="alert" aria-live="polite" id="switch-41-messages"></div><!----></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="total-price" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="total-price-text" data-v-ad830943="">TOTAL PRICE</div><div class="discounted-price without-discount" data-v-ad830943="">1204,40$</div><div class="price-purchase-button" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="price" data-v-ad830943="">730<span class="smalltext" data-v-ad830943="">,35</span><span class="euro" data-v-ad830943="">€</span></div><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--elevated v-theme--light v-btn--density-default elevation-5 v-btn--size-x-large v-btn--variant-elevated purchase-button" data-v-ad830943="" style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68); height: 70px; width: 202px;"><span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span><!----><span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator=""><i class="mdi-cash-multiple mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default purchase-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-v-ad830943="" style="color: rgb(241, 241, 241); caret-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);"></i><div class="purchase text" data-v-ad830943="">PURCHASE</div></span><!----><!----></button></div></div><div class="receipt" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="text-recepit" data-v-ad830943="">RECEIPT</div></div><div class="receipt-items" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="item-titles" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="item-title" data-v-ad830943="">Item</div><div class="item-ID" data-v-ad830943="">ID</div><div class="item-amount" data-v-ad830943="">Amount</div></div><div class="items" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="item" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="item-title" data-v-ad830943="">Eloboosting Service</div><div class="item-ID" data-v-ad830943="">Bronze I・Immortal III</div><div class="item-amount" data-v-ad830943="">541,00€</div></div></div></div><div class="discount-code-text" data-v-ad830943="">Discount Code:</div><div class="in-total" data-v-ad830943=""><div class="in-total-text" data-v-ad830943="">IN TOTAL</div><div class="in-total-price" data-v-ad830943=""> 730,35€</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>



<div id="eJOY__extension_root" class="eJOY__extension_root_class" style="all: unset;"></div><iframe id="nr-ext-rsicon" style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 50px; height: 50px; z-index: 2147483647; border-style: none; background: transparent;"></iframe><div class="v-overlay-container"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="v-overlay v-overlay--absolute v-theme--light v-locale--is-ltr v-tooltip" id="v-tooltip-32" role="tooltip" data-v-fe7abde9="" style="z-index: 2000;"><!----><div class="v-overlay__content" target="[object HTMLElement]" style="min-width: 0px; display: none;">BOOSTER SEÇEBİLİRSİN</div></div><div class="v-overlay v-overlay--absolute v-theme--light v-locale--is-ltr v-tooltip" id="v-tooltip-34" role="tooltip" data-v-fe7abde9="" style="z-index: 2000;"><!----><div class="v-overlay__content" target="[object HTMLElement]" style="min-width: 0px; display: none;">AGENTLARI SEÇEBİLİRİSİNZ</div></div><div class="v-overlay v-overlay--absolute v-theme--light v-locale--is-ltr v-tooltip" id="v-tooltip-36" role="tooltip" data-v-fe7abde9="" style="z-index: 2000;"><!----><div class="v-overlay__content" target="[object HTMLElement]" style="min-width: 0px; display: none;">Bonus win istiyorsan buna tıkla</div></div><div class="v-overlay v-overlay--absolute v-theme--light v-locale--is-ltr v-tooltip" id="v-tooltip-40" role="tooltip" data-v-fe7abde9="" style="z-index: 2000;"><!----><div class="v-overlay__content" target="[object HTMLElement]" style="min-width: 0px; display: none;">premium istiyorsan tamı tamına şu yanımdaki şeye basabilirisin</div></div></div></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
.v-btn--active > .v-btn__overlay, .v-btn[aria-haspopup=menu][aria-expanded=true] > .v-btn__overlay, .v-btn__overlay {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

This should work, because the `.v-btn__overlay` is overridden by its declaration on its own.

To address the class within the upper contaning class:

```
.buttons .v-btn__overlay{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

The CSS should work. For further investigation, take a look at this question: [Scoped CSS not being applied within the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321592/scoped-css-not-being-applied-within-the-component)

> For some reason, scoped styles don't get applied during hot reload when they are first added to the component. Full page reload fixes the issue, from there the styles, since they have been detected, get updated with consecutive hot reloads.

Comment: no doesn't work, is there any additional information I can provide for this question?

Comment: oh... well, if you could upload the html output of the code, that would be a big help.

Comment: I edit question, this is what you want? If not, sorry. I'm not very good at this kind of thing.

Comment: No, I (and we) need the output. If you press Ctrl+U and then copy the html from there and paste it here, *that* would help.

Comment: Ctrl + U give me https://prnt.sc/zMRCI_6nqGor no more

Comment: ...I see. Then in the inspection, right-click on the body tag and then select "Edit as HTML", and then copy-and-paste-here.

Comment: I edited, sorry late answer 30000 characters limit issue

Comment: This is what we would need (the "output"): https://prnt.sc/2-y1OqLOEGu6 the code as I marked in red "square".

Comment: Okay, sorry, now this should be what you want, not formatted code because formatted code highter than 30000 characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253899/discussion-between-iorgv-and-skyturkish).