# How to correctly use "scoped" styles in VueJS single file components?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

The [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) on VueJS state that `scoped` should limit styles to the component. But if I create 2 components with same `baz` style, it will leak from one component into another:

`foo.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="baz">
    <Bar></Bar>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.baz {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

`bar.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="baz">bar</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.baz {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

I expect that `baz` will be different in both components. But after generating a web page, I can see the red text on blue background, which means that `foo`'s scoped style affects the `bar` component. The generated code looks like this:

```
<div class="baz" data-v-ca22f368>
  <div class="baz" data-v-a0c7f1ce data-v-ca22f368>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the "leak" is intentionally generated by VueJS via specifying two data attributes into the `bar` component. But why?

Comment: It might be a special case as the two components are nested. Don't know if it qualifies as a bug, though.

Answer (score 61):

You can read on the [Vue loader's docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html#notes):

> A child component's root node will be affected by both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS.

This is apparently what it is meant to do, even though it might seem a bit confusing.

If you want to avoid that, you should use [css modules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/css-modules.html):

```
<template>
<div :class="$style.baz">
  <Bar></Bar>
</div>
</template>

<style module>
.baz {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Well done. That's some seriously impressive interpretation. The above docs quote is so mind-warping that it might as well just be a low-res gif of a mobius strip illustration.

Comment: Could this also be stated as: “a parent component’s scoped style will still affect any descendant”? I am asking sincerely

Comment: Not quite @Jared . "A child component's root node" - first element within <template>, often a <div>, within the child component. If you move the class one level lower you avoid that "clashing" of styles.

Answer (score 2):

**2021**

I found an answer, styles from parent are applied to child components but only for first direct children e.g. when we have button component

```
<template>
   <button class='btn' />
</template>
```

With this you can style your btn class from parent to aviod that you need to wrap your btn component with some dummy div or the best use vue-fragment library and you will avoid style leaking problem with `scoped` attribute.

```
<template>
   <fragment>
      <button class='btn' />
   </fragment>
</template>
```

With this you are not able to style btn class inside your child component.

Full Example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-fog-2mu5z?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Vue Fragment:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment

Comment: Check this out: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-vue-deep-css-selector

Comment: Yeah I know and with vuetify u simply use ::v-deep pseudo element, nice article thank you