# VueJS - v-bind:style + hover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use CSS hover with VueJS v-bind:style directive but couldn't find information regarding it.

I need to bind styles for hover but `v-bind:style.hover={}`
doesn't work. All the properties are going to be fetched from back-end, so I need to bind styles dynamically.

Are there other ways to bind styles on mouse over or CSS hover using VueJS?

Here is my code

This is the object  :

```
button: {
    colorBackd: '#1e2021',
    colorBackdHover: '#000000',
    text: 'Results',
    color: '#d3e0ff',
    colorHover: "#ffffff",
    borderColor: '#d3e0ff',
    borderColorHover: "#ffffff"
},
```

Here is the html element that needs to be bound with styles

```
<button type="button"
    :style="{
    color:button.color,
        backgroundColor:button.colorBackd,
        borderColor:button.borderColor,
    }"
    class="btn btn-outline-info large-button">

        {{ button.text }}

</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Improved solution: use CSS custom properties and variables

If you only intend to work with modern/evergreen browsers, then using CSS custom properties and variables is the way to go! You can actually pass CSS custom properties into the `:style` binding, e.g.

```
computed: {
  styleObject: function() {
    return {
      '--color': this.button.color,
      '--color-hover': this.button.colorHover
    }
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<custom-button :style="styleObject" />
```

For the CSS, it's just a matter of:

```
button {
  color: var(--color);
}

button:hover {
  color: var(--color-hover);
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you can scope CSS custom properties, so these variables will only apply to your specific button component when you define the CSS properties at the element level (instead of in `:root`).

The only drawback is that you have to iteratively declare all the variables in both hover and unhovered states, which can be a little bit cumbersome. However, I see this is a very minor disadvantage, compared to the benefits that you reap from using CSS variables.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var customButton = Vue.component('custom-button', {
  template: '#custom-button',
  data() {
    return {
      button: {
        colorBackd: '#1e2021',
        colorBackdHover: '#000000',
        text: 'Results',
        color: '#d3e0ff',
        colorHover: "#ffffff",
        borderColor: '#d3e0ff',
        borderColorHover: "#ffffff"
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject() {
      return {
        '--button-color': this.button.color,
        '--button-background-color': this.button.colorBackd,
        '--button-border-color': this.button.borderColor,
        
        '--button-color--hover': this.button.colorHover,
        '--button-background-color--hover': this.button.colorBackdHover,
        '--button-border-color': this.button.borderColorHover
      };
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
button {
  color: var(--button-color);
  background-color: var(--button-background-color);
  border-color: var(--button-border-color);
}

button:hover {
  color: var(--button-color--hover);
  background-color: var(--button-background-color--hover);
  border-color: var(--button-border-color--hover);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-button></custom-button>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="custom-button">
  <button type="button" :style="styleObject" class="btn btn-outline-info large-button">
        {{ button.text }}
  </button>
</script>
```

### Original sotluion: use JS-based mouse events

You can store the hovered state of the element in its `data`, say `hoverState`. It is set to `false` by default, and is toggled to `true` when `@mouseenter` is fired, and back to `false` when `@mouseleave` is triggered:

Then, you can simply bind a **computed property** to the `style` attribute, for example, `styleObject`. In this `styleObject`, you can return the correct CSS styles depending on the `hoverState` found in the component's data:

```js
var customButton = Vue.component('custom-button', {
  template: '#custom-button',
  data() {
    return {
      button: {
        colorBackd: '#1e2021',
        colorBackdHover: '#000000',
        text: 'Results',
        color: '#d3e0ff',
        colorHover: "#ffffff",
        borderColor: '#d3e0ff',
        borderColorHover: "#ffffff"
      },
      hoverState: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject() {
      var modifier = '';
      if (this.hoverState)
        modifier = 'Hover';
        
      return {
        color: this.button['color' + modifier],
        backgroundColor: this.button['colorBackd' + modifier],
        borderColor: this.button['borderColor' + modifier]
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateHoverState(isHover) {
      this.hoverState = isHover;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-button></custom-button>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="custom-button">
  <button type="button" :style="styleObject" @mouseenter="updateHoverState(true)" @mouseleave="updateHoverState(false)" class="btn btn-outline-info large-button">
        {{ button.text }}
  </button>
</script>
```

Comment: this works but feels like a really convoluted way of doing it. It would be nice if there were modifiers for the `:style` attribute.

Comment: @EdShee Actually, there is :) if you look at using CSS custom properties and variables, that's entirely possible: and without the need to bind mouseevents. I've updated my answer to reflect this new possibility.

Answer (score 5):

**Other way (using css variables).**

You need create HTML with style

```
<style>
     div[vueid=${_uid}] { --btn-hover: ${`Here your hover brush`} }
</style>
```

and inject it into your component.

```
<template>
   <div vueid="_uid">
      <button></button>
      <div v-html="styleCode"></div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Then simply use this variable in static `css` file to setup button style.

```
button:hover { background: var(--btn-hover); }
```

Note: you can describe default variable value in `:root` selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your Vuejs Component an id and apply the required hover style in a stylesheet.

```
<button id="styledButton" type="button"
:style="{
color:button.color,
    backgroundColor:button.colorBackd,
    borderColor:button.borderColor,
}"
class="btn btn-outline-info large-button">

    {{ button.text }}
</button>
```

then in  tag,

```
<style>
styledButton:hover {
color: #FFFFFF
};
</style>
```

If you want the hover style to contain any dynamic data. make a  tag that calls a computed property.

```
<style>{{computedStyle}}</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using vue3 with composition api and decided there's 2 good ways to do this. You can use a slot and variable like so:

```
<MenuItem v-slot="{ active }">
  <a href="#" :class="[active ? 'bg-neutral-600' : '', text-sm']">File</a>
</MenuItem>
```

Or you can use any template variables in the CSS section with v-bind() like so:

```
<template>
  <MenuItem class="menuClass">File</MenuItem>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  setup() {
    return {
      myObject,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.menuClass:hover {
  background-color: v-bind("myObject.hoverColor");
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use single file components, then you just need to make the button style scoped:

```
<template>
    <button></button>
</template>

<style scoped>
    button {
        /* your button style here */
    }
</style>
```

Or even for a more confined styling there are modules, shown here: [How to correctly use "scoped" styles in VueJS single file components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898865/how-to-correctly-use-scoped-styles-in-vuejs-single-file-components)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing this is not implemented in vue I decided to use an overlay, which adds up to using :style to the overlay that will be shown by changing the opacity.

It is basically:

```
<div id="test" :style="style">
  <div class="overlay" :style="style.hover"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var testArea = Vue.component('test-area', {
  template: '<div id="test" :style="style"><div class="overlay" :style="style.hover"></div></div>',
  computed: {
    style() {
      return {
        backgroundColor: '#0f0',
        hover: {
          backgroundColor: '#f00'
        }
      };
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#test>.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}

#test:hover>.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test-area></test-area>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change z-index on hover so that hovered p tag appears at top. To do so I had to listen for event along with some value.

[image][image][image]

```
<template>
...
<p @mouseover="changeZIndex"
   @mouseleave="changeZIndexToOriginal({$event,old_z_index})
>
...
</template>


<script>
...methods
changeZIndex(e){
    //change to new z-index
    e.target.style.zIndex = 5 //to show on top
}
changeZIndexToOriginal(e){
    //e.$event is  an event which is trirgered. to get event along with some value we have to use this approach
    // e.old_z_index is z-index that I want to set back again. I am just using loop index to set z-index
    e.$event.target.style.zIndex = e.old_z_index
}
...
</script>
```

Using above approach we can change anything related to target element.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple solution I found was to use the `v-bind:class` directive instead:

in my case i needed to add a hover when this element is inactive:

`:class="{'inactive': !item.count}"`

In this case, I am able to add an inactive property to my class, and then i can simply style that class with `hover` properties like so:

```
.inactive {
  color: black;

  &:hover {
    background-color: green;   
  }
}
```