# Vue.js: Create css class dynamically based on attribute values

Tags: vue.js

In vue it's easy to change the class of an element dynamically. However, what I want to do has nothing to do with that:

I have an attribute `color` with the value `#333` for example. Now I want to build a css class like:

```
.myColorClass > a {
  color: this.color;
}
```

It's not possible for me to style every single element `a` individually with the style attribute. So how do I approach this problem with Vue?

Comment: Can you check this and see if this helps you (https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_var)

Comment: @Himanshu doesn't help, because the variable still is declared in css.

Comment: directly accessing the value from the data to the css isn't possible. From what I can understand, you want to add a particular style to all the anchor tags then why not to create a class containing color and just use javascript to add it to all the anchor tags.

Comment: I found the answer right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46553407/6399812

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS - v-bind:style + hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551925/vuejs-v-bindstyle-hover)

Comment: I feel like the particular solution would be a lot of work for you to just attain the styling of the anchor tag. But I don't know the exact part that you're trying to solve. See whichever solution works best for you and use the same.