# Scoped Styles are always overwritten

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, scope

I'm currently learning Vue and can't get rid of a scope problem.

**Question**:
The `profile.vue` styles keep overriding the ones from `sidebar.vue`. The sidebar should keep it's red background with this setting, while the section in the profile page should be blue. Shouldn't do `scoped` within the `style` tag this job?

**Output**:
[image]

`Profile.vue` below:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <section>
      Test
    </section>
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
  export default {
    name: "Profile",
    components: {Sidebar}
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  main {
    width: 100%;
    @include flex();

    section {
      width: 100%;
      background: blue;
      margin-left: $size*5;
    }
  }
</style>
```

`Sidebar.vue` below:

```
<template>
  <section>
    Test
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Sidebar"
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  section {
    max-width: ($size*45);
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898865/how-to-correctly-use-scoped-styles-in-vuejs-single-file-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your child-component's root element is a section

By design, a parent component is able to style the child components root.
In general this is used so you can easily style a child component, add margin, padding etc. But in your case it is conflicting.

What you see:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section>...</section>
    <your-component></your-component>
  </div>
</template>
```

What your scoped css sees:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- I can style out here -->
    <section>...</section>
    <section>
    <!-- But I can't style in here -->
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

The scoped css knows not to go INTO the component, but the components root as basically at the level that it is allowed to style, and since it's a section, the css selector is valid.

If you just wrap your child component like this, there will be no conflict:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section>...</section>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also style them with different classes etc.

Here is the [official docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs explaining this behavior:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

This has already been answered here:

[How to correctly use "scoped" styles in VueJS single file components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898865/how-to-correctly-use-scoped-styles-in-vuejs-single-file-components)