# How to apply style as default to my component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a  nested inside a  in React Native. Is there a way to tell React Native to style all nested Text Elements that are inside a specific (or all) View Element?

```
<View style={[container.header,container.super]}><Text>overview</Text></View>
```

I dont want declare style={text.headerText} or similar to every single Text element that is inside the View Element. Maybe there is something like

.container.header > Text {
...
}

like it is in classic .css

Comment: [`<style scoped>` was meant to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692033/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to create a component

```
function MyTextComponent(props) {
  return (<Text style={style.myTxtStyle}>{props.children}</Text>);
}
```

And then just instead of using Text Component use MyTextComponent like this

```
<MyTextComponent>Some text</MyTextComponent>
```