# Is possible to styling parent from child with scoped?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

Fellas, I've tried to style my parent class but inside the child component within the scoped style like this

Child component

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
  .public-page
    overflow: unset
</style>
```

which parent component class looks like this

```
.public-page
  flex: 1
  overflow: hidden
  width: 100vw
  font-size: 14px !important
  color: #233142
```

is it possible to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible to reach into parent components (and their styles) via `this.$parent`, but you are *strongly discouraged* to do so in most cases as it very tightly connects your components (styles will be weird if these components are not used in this exact configuration, and it will be unclear what causes it). For this use-case, I would add a class to the Parent component that unsets the overflow and conditionally add it to the class list when needed (from a child component's emitted event for example). Components workflow lends itself extremely well for using BEM css architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

- html5's `<style scoped>` had a brief and useful life but is no more. It was obsoleted. Some discussion at [What is the current state of the "scoped" attribute for the style element in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633038/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-scoped-attribute-for-the-style-element-in-htm)
- [Vue.js's <style scoped>](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles) applies to the current component.

Comment: `<style scoped>`  is still used extensively in the .vue SFC. I believe this is unrelated from the obsoleted HTML5 implementation. During compilation, `webpack/vue-loader` interprets the `<style>` tag in every SFC to add it into a main css file. The `scoped` attribute then makes it so that every generated DOM node gets a unique data attribute, and all style rules in this component get a suffix selector for that unique data attribute, effectively scoping the styles per component.

Comment: so looking at https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles — `vue.js`'s  `<style scoped>` applies to the *current* component?