# Scoped CSS doesn't work and the styles get leaked out

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS file called "stylesheet.css"

```css
p {
    margin: 0%;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 1cm;
}

h1 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

And I have an html file in the same folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test</p>
        <h1>Test</h1>

        <div>
            <style scoped>
                @import "stylesheet.css";
            </style>
            <p>Test (Supposed to be bigger and different font)</p>
            <h1>Test (Should have a different font)</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason, the style rules that I had imported in a scoped style tag in a div leaks out to the body and styles the p tag above: [image]

Comment: scoped is not a standard css keyword. In your sample it look like the vue keyword scoped that apply style only on current component

Comment: The `<style scoped>` attribute was an experiment from 2011 to 2015. Browsers haven't supported it for years. Unfortunately there's a lot of _plain wrong_ blog-articles and even [highly-visible StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28633038/159145) all written before 2015 that really should be archived by now (also, the `:scope` selector in CSS is a completely different topic entirely).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers [do not support `scoped`](https://caniuse.com/?search=scoped) which has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#deprecated_attributes).

Even if they did support it, your CSS is targetting the `body` element and there isn't a `body` element inside the `div` that you are scoping the CSS to (and can't be, since a `body` element isn't allowed there).

Write your CSS to target the elements you actually have.

```css
#scopeTarget {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 1cm;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>

<div id="scopeTarget">
  <p>Test (Supposed to be bigger and different font)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaikLowrey — You *can*, but [`<link>` is preferered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199377/19068) and `<style>` elements are not allowed as descendants of the `<body>` element.