# The w3.org validator eror

Tags: html, w3c-validation

The w3.org validator is giving me this error:

```
Line 322, Column 29: Element style is missing required attribute scoped.
<style type="text/css">
```

style my html code :

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For Gravity forms addon in wordpress .

```
    <style type="text/css">
.gright,.gform_wrapper form ,.gform_wrapper ul li:before, .gform_wrapper ul li:after, .gform_wrapper ul.gform_fields {
text-align: right !important;
direction:rtl !important;
}
.gleft,.gform_wrapper input[type="url"], .gform_wrapper input[type="email"],
.gform_wrapper input[type="tel"], .gform_wrapper input[type="number"], 
.gform_wrapper input[type="password"],body.rtl .gform_wrapper input[type="email"], body.rtl .gform_wrapper input[type="password"],
body.rtl .gform_wrapper input[type="url"], body.rtl .gform_wrapper input[type="tel"],body .gform_wrapper.gf_rtl_wrapper input[type="email"],
body .gform_wrapper.gf_rtl_wrapper input[type="password"], body .gform_wrapper.gf_rtl_wrapper input[type="url"], body .gform_wrapper.gf_rtl_wrapper input[type="tel"] {
text-align:left !important;
direction:ltr !important;
}
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_left {
float: right !important;
}
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_right {
float: left !important;
                        }
                        .gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox li label,
                        .gform_wrapper .gfield_radio li label {
                            margin-right:20px !important;
                        }↩
                        .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex.ginput_container.has_first_name.has_middle_name.has_last_name span.name_first,
                        .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex.ginput_container.has_first_name.has_middle_name.has_last_name span.name_middle,
                        .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex.ginput_container.has_first_name.no_middle_name.has_last_name span.name_first{
                            margin-right:0px !important;
                            margin-left: 1.3% !important;
                        }
                    </style>
```

Please help me fix in html or addon in wordpress.

Comment: Missing `</style>`, `<style>` should be in the `<head>`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539084 ?
-> Either move style to head as Alex K. suggested, or use the scoped attribute.

Comment: no - not fixed - help me

Comment: Remove  <style> from <body>.

Comment: note that the `type` attribute for both `<style>` and `<script>` tags are useless in HTML5 unless you use something else than respectively CSS and javascript...

Comment: This is not necessarily a "typo" as some suggest as shown by the validator's error where it complains about a missing attribute and not the style element's location.

Answer (score 1):

The `<style>` element can have the `scoped` attribute applied to a section of a page and needs to be "scoped" to contain it in that section.

> If present, it indicates that the styles are intended just for the
>   subtree rooted at the style element's parent element, as opposed to
>   the whole Document.

By putting the style element inside the body, the validator assumes you are trying to do this and, when you don't, flags it as an error. So, the error will go away if you do as others suggested and properly put the style inside the head element where it belongs or, otherwise, properly scope the style as the specification says. However, I don't recall if browsers do this yet.