# Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: html, w3c

I have been going through W3C errors and have cleared all but this one.

> Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context.

Here is the code it refers to:

```
<style><!--ul.lists { width: 29%; float: left;}--></style>
```

Any help ridding me of this last error would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code??

Comment: Sounds like you put a `<style>` block as a child of a `<div>`. Move it to your `<head>`.

Comment: Can you please put the whole code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context (<style scoped> not validating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539084/element-style-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-body-in-this-context-style-scope)

Comment: hi, sorry, how do i put the whole code?

Answer (score 2):

The W3C error message describes your problem and a possible solution very well:

> The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- **such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head"** -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

You have to move your `<style>` to the `<head>` area of the site.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul.lists {
        width: 29%;
        float: left;
      }
      /* this is a CSS comment. */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <!-- this is a HTML comment. -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**You try to comment some code?**

You are using the comment syntax for HTML instead of CSS. You try to comment the CSS code inside `<style>` with `<!-- ... -->`. You have to use the CSS syntax `/* ... */` instead.

Comment: Great, i just placed it in the head. It works as well as before but now i don't have a w3c issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

In style tags and CSS files, you use `/* ... */`  for commenting things out, not the HTML way of commenting like `<!-- ... -->`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do an inline style you can use

```
<ul style="width:29%;float:left"></ul>
```

Or put the code in a .css file

```
ul.lists {
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
}
```

And declare the class in the HTML

```
<ul class="lists"></ul>
```

To comment in CSS you must use `/* this is a comment */`