# Element style not allowed as child of element

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2aRD.png)

This is the error I got, please help someone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context (<style scoped> not validating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539084/element-style-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-body-in-this-context-style-scope)

Comment: No, Because the scope attribute is removed from HTML.